# Ayuda con este Problema de JAVA

Tags: java

```
package problema.pkg7.pkg2;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Problema72 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
              Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;     
        int num3;
        int producto;
        int suma;

        System.out.print("Ingrese el Primer Valor");
        num1 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.print("Ingrese el Segundo Valor");
        num2 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.print("Ingrese el Tercer Valor");
        num3 = input.nextInt ();

        suma = num1 + num2 + num3;
        producto = num1 * num2 * num3;

        int n= sc.nextInt();
      if(n==0){
              System.out.println("El numero "+n+" es positivo");
          }else{
          System.out.println("El numero "+n+" es negativo");
          }



      System.out.print("La Suma de los 3 Valores Es" +suma);

      System.out.print("El Resultado De Los 3 Productos Es");
```

Comment: Hola DOOM, ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: Hola Doom, bienvenido a [es.so]. Puedes explicar mejor tu prbolema con ese codigo? te da errores o resultados inesperados? Recuerda **leer el [tour]** para aprender como funciona el sitio y [ask] para ver como hacer preguntas de más calidad. Un saludo

Comment: no se que tenga que poner para que realice esas funciones@lois6b

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es explicar en tu pregunta tu problema. Ahora mismo muestras un codigo no? explicanos por que ese codigo no hace lo que pides o donde falla o que falta o que errores te da. Mejora la pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el código hay unos cuantos fallos de sintaxis así como de comprensión de lo que te han pedido.
Aquí te dejo una modificación de tu codigo:

```
package problema.pkg7.pkg2;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Problema72 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
              Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int num1;
        int num2;     
        int num3;
        int producto;
        int suma;

        System.out.print("Ingrese el Primer Valor");
        num1 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.print("Ingrese el Segundo Valor");
        num2 = input.nextInt ();

        System.out.print("Ingrese el Tercer Valor");
        num3 = input.nextInt ();
       // ANTES DE REALIZAR LA SUMA O EL PRODUCTO COMPROBAR SI ES NEGATIVO
        if (num1 <0){
         // El valor es negativo
         producto = num1 * num2 * num3;    
         System.out.print("El Resultado De Los 3 Productos Es: "+ producto);
        } else{
         // El valor es positivo
         suma = num1 + num2 + num3;                 
         System.out.print("La Suma de los 3 Valores Es: " +suma);
        }
```

Esta parte de tu código no sé que es lo que quieres hacer:

```
int n= sc.nextInt(); // EL PRIMER NÚMERO QUE INSERTAS ES LA VARIABLE num1
      if(n==0){ // SI N == 0 ES POSITIVO, PERO SI ES MAYOR A 0 NO?
              System.out.println("El numero "+n+" es positivo");
          }else{ // TODO LO QUE NO SEA IGUAL A 0 ES NEGATIVO?
          System.out.println("El numero "+n+" es negativo");
          }
```

En los comentarios que he puesto te muestro la confusión del **if**, las condiciones son:

1. **== (Igual a)**
2. **!= (Distinto a)**
3. **<= (Menor o igual a)**
4. **>= (Mayor o igual a)**
5. **< (Menor que)**
6. **> (Mayor que)**